# How can I store data in global variable out side Alamofire in Swift

Tags: json, xcode, swift, alamofire

I did try to get data from web services which is Dictionary data type by using librar which are Alamofire and SwiftJSON.  My problem is I cannot store data in global variable which is outside the Alamofire.

Here are my codes.

```
var productsAll:JSON = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON {
        (request, response, json, error) in


        if json != nil {


            var jsonObj = JSON(json!)


               var data = jsonObj["product"].dictionaryObject

                 self.productsAll = JSON(data!)

                println("out form in side \(self.productsAll)")

        }
    }

}
```

When I println productAll inside viewDidLoad()  I get Json data type.

```
out form in side {
 "tax_class" : "",
 "related_ids" : [

],
"on_sale" : false,
"taxable" : false,
"variations" : [

],
"description" : "<p><b id=\"mf528\">ZALORA<\/b> <\/p>\n",
"average_rating" : "0.00",
"managing_stock" : false,
"shipping_class_id" : null,
"backorders_allowed" : false,
"id" : 4636,
 ]
 ]
 ]
}
}
```

But when I println productAll somewhere else out side viewDidLoad. I get nothing.

```
[

]
```

How can I store data productAll in Alamofire to global variable

```
var productsAll:JSON = []
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that your content is already loaded. Alamofire works asynchronously, triggers the closure when data is loaded and only then parses and assigns productsAll . Maybe you are simply printing the content too early?

Comment: Thank tgebarowski. You make me think to something "reloadData()" and it work.

Comment: can you post what you did? thank you